# Bash script working from terminal but not from AWS Systems Manager

Tags: linux, bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-eks, aws-ssm

I am using below bash script inside AWS EC2 (ubuntu) to assume a role for AWS EKS and then restart a specific service

```
#!/bin/bash
export $(printf "AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=%s AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=%s AWS_SESSION_TOKEN=%s" \
$(aws sts assume-role \
--role-arn arn:aws:iam::1234567890:role/someRole \
--role-session-name MySessionName \
--query "Credentials.[AccessKeyId,SecretAccessKey,SessionToken]" \
--output text))

aws eks --region us-east-1 update-kubeconfig --name cluster-main

kubectl rollout restart deployment/abc-service -n xyz
```

I am running the above script in terminal using `source test.sh`(assuming test.sh is script name) . Its all working fine from terminal. But when I am trying to automate and run the same script from AWS Systems Manager - Run Command feature then it is throwing me error. Below is the script which is being used inside AWS Systems Manager - Run Command to run this

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo su
cd /home/ubuntu
source test.sh
```

But it is failing and showing me below error

```
The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?

failed to run commands: exit status 1
```

Looks like from Systems Manager it cant access kubectl or some other issue. Any idea what I am doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: I thought this was a duplicate question at first, but it's the next step in your puzzle. There are a lot of things that are likely wrong here and it's tough to give an actual answer. This seems like something odd to run via SSM because it doesn't perform any actual action on the host, it only interacts with AWS and k8s APIs. For troubleshooting, you need more logs. The error message indicates there was an earlier failure in the `update-kubeconfig` command, but I would rethink what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Just tried running only " aws eks --region us-east-1 update-kubeconfig --name vgp-main " using AWS SSM and its shows command successfully run. 

Updated context arn:aws:eks:us-east-1:1234567899:cluster/abc-main in /root/.kube/config